# Group action of $ GL_{n}(R) $ on the set of $ n-1 $ dimensional linear subspaces of $ R^{n} $ by linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Can't wrap my head around this one. If the group action is on $\mathbb{R}^{n} $, then that's not a problem. We have $ n \times n $ matrix and $ n $-vector. But what if vectors are from $ \mathbb{R}^{n-1} $? Could someone explain or give a link to some reading?
Thanks.

Comment: You night be misreading the question: the action is not on $\Bbb R^{n-1}$, but on the space formed of all the hyperplanes of $\Bbb R^n$ - a particular case of [Grassmann manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian).

Comment: Vectors are from $\mathbb{R}^n$, you just happen to consider a bunch of them that form a $n-1$-dimensional subspace. If $k\le n$, $g \in GL_n(\mathbb{R}) $ and $V\subset \mathbb{R} ^n$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$,  then $g. V=\{g. v, v \in V\} $ is also a $k$-dimensional subspace. This is only defined within the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, those vectors simply have $ 0 $ for one of "coordinates"? i.e, $ (0, x_{2},...,x_{n}) $?

Comment: @user369044 No, but they are all isomorphic to a subspace of that form. An hyperplane (a subspace of dimension $n-1$) in $\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace defined by an equation of the form $a_1x_1+\cdots + a_nx_n=0$ where not all the $a_i$ are zero.

Comment: No. SUbspaces arise in infinitely many ways as solutions of any single linear homogeneous equation. fFr example, vectors in which sum of all components is zero.  The vector $(1,1,\ldots,1, n-1)$ is a vector where no coordinate is zero.

Comment: Thanks much to everyone for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a group$G$ acts on a set $X$, there is an associated action on the collection of subsets of $X$.

For example if  $A\subset X$, then define $g.A$ to be the subset $\{g.a\mid a\in A\}$.

In fact by fixing the cardinality of subsets we can also define action on subsets of  cardinality $r$.

Now coming to your question. $X$ is a vector space., and the action is by (invertible) linear transformations (not just permutations of $X$).

Take the subsets $A$ to be vector subspaces of fixed dimension. There is an associated action on this collection. As $g$ is  an invertible linear transformation $g.A$ will have the same dimension as $A$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. If we are working in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, we'll get transformations of hyperplanes that pass through origin, correct?

Comment: Yes, any subspace must "pass" through the origin, since any subspace must include the zero, i.e., identity, vector.